# PHP echo/print change text font colour on text from array

Tags: php, html

Hi I have small problem with changing colour of font from array, printing things works fine.

```
<?php print $Pobierz_wsyzstkie [1]; ?>
<?php echo $Pobierz_wsyzstkie [3]; ?>
```

This works fine, write what they should. But if i try to colour the array output with code like this:

```
   <?php echo "<span style='color:blue;'>$Pobierz_wsyzstkie 
   [3]</span>"; ?>
```

I get coloured text but is not text from array,  this shows "Array [3]".

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this (note the quotes and dots to separate and connect PHP and HTML string output):

```
<?php echo "<span style='color:blue;'>".$Pobierz_wsyzstkie[3]."</span>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between your variable and your square brackets. This is the direct cause of the issue. Also, correctly concatenate your variables within your string.

Here;

```
<?php 
   echo "<span style='color:blue;'>".$Pobierz_wsyzstkie[3]."</span>";
?>
```

## Best Practises :

- The PHP open and close tags should be on their own lines.
- Array references (keys) should not have a space between them and their array variable name (`$Pobierz_wsyzstkie[3]` not "$Pobierz_wsyzstkie [3]")
- Learn about the correct [PHP String Concatenation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).
- PHP variables (`$Pobierz_wsyzstkie`) should start with a lower case letter.
- CSS styles should not be inline but instead should be in their own CSS file.